# bash parent and child signal handling

Tags: bash, trap

Quick summary: parent and child in a loop, each can either trap or not trap signals. I don't understand why, if the child traps and the parent doesn't, the parent is not terminated.

The detail:

I have two simple scripts, which just run a loop, and optionally trap SIGINT and other signals. The child script is launched by the parent.

Parent:

```
#!/bin/bash

parent_trap=$1
child_trap=$2

shutdown=0

(( parent_trap )) && trap "echo 'parent: caught signal'; shutdown=1" INT TERM HUP PIPE

while (( ! shutdown )) ; do
    echo parent
    ./child $child_trap
    sleep 1
done
```

Child:

```
#!/bin/bash

child_trap=$1

shutdown=0

(( child_trap )) && trap "echo 'child: caught signal'; shutdown=1" INT TERM HUP PIPE

while (( ! shutdown )) ; do
    echo child
    sleep 1
done
```

When these are run with the four combinations of trapping signals:

no trapping:

```
$ ./parent 0 0
parent
child
child
child
^C
```

parent and child are both terminated by ctrl-c. As I understand it, the shell sends SIGINT to all processes in the process group, there are no handlers, so the default action of terminate is invoked.

parent and child both trap:

```
$ ./parent 1 1
parent
child
child
child
^Cchild: caught signal
parent: caught signal
```

parent and child both catch signal and both exit cleanly

parent traps signal, child does not:

```
$ ./parent 1 0
parent
child
child
child
^Cparent: caught signal
```

parent catches signal and exits cleanly. child is killed by terminate (I think)

child traps signal, parent does not:

```
$ ./parent 0 1
parent
child
child
child
^Cchild: caught signal
parent
child
^Cchild: caught signal
parent
child
^Cchild: caught signal
^C
```

child traps signal and exits cleanly, but parent, which does not trap signal continues (relaunching child) until ctrl-c is pressed twice in quick succession.

Why isn't the parent terminated as the default action when there is no signal handler?

Comment: The correct answer is to rewrite your scripts to not use signals. As you've found out, they are very confusing. Few programmers know the arcane details of bash signal handling; it should be possible to accomplish whatever you're trying to do in more mainstream ways.

Comment: Good suggestion, but that's not an option if I don't control "child"